# atom package submit button not driving submit function

Tags: atom-editor

I have a simple atom package where I'm attempting to read some input from the user:

```
$ = jQuery = require 'jquery'

module.exports =
  class InputView
    constructor: (serializedState) ->
      console.log('InputView: entered ctor')
      @element = document.createElement('div')
      @element.classList.add('input-view')

      form = $('<form/>').attr(
        action: @doIt
      ).appendTo(@element)

      $('<input/>').attr(
        type: 'text'
        name: 'msg'
      ).appendTo(form)

      $('<input/>').attr(
        type: 'submit'
        value: 'doit'
      ).appendTo(form)

    attach: ->
      console.log('InputView: entered attach')

    getElement: ->
      return @element

    doIt: ->
      console.log('now in doIt')
```

Which generates the following when I toggle my package:

[image]

But when I click *doit*, the function *doIt* is not driven.

The function *is* driven during initialization though (from console):

```
InputView: entered ctor
now in doIt
VtAtomPkgTest (cs3) was toggled!
```

The main package looks like:

```
'use babel';
$ = jQuery = require 'jquery'

VtAtomPkgTestView = require './vt-atom-pkg-test-view'
InputView = require './input-view'
{CompositeDisposable} = require 'atom'

module.exports = VtAtomPkgTest =
  vtAtomPkgTestView: null,
  modalPanel: null,
  subscriptions: null,
  inputView: null,
  inputViewPanel: null

  activate: (state) ->
    @vtAtomPkgTestView = new VtAtomPkgTestView(state.vtAtomPkgTestViewState);
    @modalPanel = atom.workspace.addModalPanel(
      item: @vtAtomPkgTestView.getElement(),
      visible: false
    );
    @inputView = new InputView(state.inputViewState)
    @inputViewPanel = atom.workspace.addModalPanel(
      item: @inputView.getElement(),
      visible: false
    );

    #Events subscribed to in atom's system can be easily cleaned up with a CompositeDisposable
    @subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable

    # Register command that toggles this view
    @subscriptions.add atom.commands.add 'atom-workspace',
      'vt-atom-pkg-test:toggle':  => @toggle()

  deactivate: () ->
    @modalPanel.destroy()
    @subscriptions.dispose()
    @vtAtomPkgTestView.destroy()
    @inputView.destroy()
    @inputViewPanel.destroy()

  serialize: () ->
      vtAtomPkgTestViewState: @vtAtomPkgTestView.serialize()

  toggle: () ->
    console.log('VtAtomPkgTest (cs3) was toggled!');
    console.log('VtAtomPkgTest.toggle: core.themes=' + atom.config.get('core.themes'))
    #console.log('VtAtomPkgTest.toggle: jquery version=' + $.fn.jquery)
    if @modalPanel.isVisible()
      @modalPanel.hide()
      @inputViewPanel.hide()
    else
      @modalPanel.show()
      @inputViewPanel.show()
```

A) What am I doing wrong?
B) Is using a form the recommended way to get simple input data in an Atom package?

Answer (score 0):

A) This had nothing to do with atom, and everything to do with jQuery.  I should have posted this question to the jQuery forum rather than the Atom forum.  Anyway, I just had to rewrite the syntax on my form object to have *.submit()*.  The final form and input expression now looks like:

```
  form = $('<form/>').attr( id: 'input-form').submit(@doIt)

  form.appendTo(@element)

  $('<input/>').attr(
    type: 'text'
    name: 'msg'
  ).appendTo(form)

  $('<input/>').attr(
    type: 'submit'
    value: 'doit'
  ).appendTo(form)
```

I'm sure there are better ways to express it with jQuery, but this is good enough for now.

B) I think my second question is wrong in its intent. You shouldn't ask what's the appropriate way to ask for input in the *atom editor*.  Rather, you should ask what's the appropriate way to ask for input in a *web page* i.e. just think of the Atom panel as a web page.

So the answer to using a form is "It depends" : sometimes it's a good solution, and other times  things like a drop-down would be better etc.